# How do you cook flavored pasta?

Tags: pasta, italian-cuisine

How do you cook special pasta that is flavored (tomato, squid etc)? Do you salt the water the same way? Should you incorporate less flavorful sauces to not mask the initial flavor of the pasta?

Comment: Flavor pairings are a matter of opinion and generally off topic.

Answer (score 5):

You cook it the same way as you cook "regular" pasta.

As for the sauces, try to keep it related to the flavor of the pasta.

Squid ink pasta should be used with seafood sauces (vongole...)

For tomato pasta or spinach pasta, I tend to keep the sauce as light as possible; just olive oil, garlic, little bit of herb as to not hide the pasta colors; no cream sauce, no full-on tomato sauce or ragu sauce.